# Why callback function has null as first argument?

Tags: javascript, function, authentication

I read everything what I could find,but still I do not understand this.

Passportjs authentication(Twitter)
[authorize](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authorize/)

```
function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
    Account.findOne({ domain: 'twitter.com', uid: profile.id }, function(err, account) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (account) { return done(null, account); }
```

Why is the err callback only with oneargument,and the second account callback has also null argument?

Comment: I assume the first argument is the error, if any. You have to check the documentation to make sure, though.

Comment: "the err callback only with one" one what?

Comment: In NodeJS callbacks there is the "error first" callbacks convention. The first argument is always an error, null otherwise

Comment: @CristianTraìna Arugment,will edit.

Comment: This question is lacking context. As the function is anonymous, it's likely being passed as a parameter to something else. This "something else" is an important detail that you have skipped over.

Comment: @TrajcheS the `done` function is a callback too. And since it's a callback, it respects the "error-first" convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` in this code is also a callback function which conforms to a convention called [error first](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/)

> There’s really only two rules for defining an error-first callback:
>
> - The first argument of the callback is reserved for an error object. If an error occurred, it will be returned by the first err argument.
> - The second argument of the callback is reserved for any successful response data. If no error occurred, err will be set to null and any successful data will be returned in the second argument.

Therefore when an error occurs `done` is called with a single parameter - the error. When no error occurs `done` is called with 2 parameters. The first is null (no error) the second is the sucessful response details.